# OpenAI fine tuning for classification alternative

Tags: python, openai-api

I wrote this snippet for classifying the data:

```
result=openai.File.create(file=open("train.jsonl"),purpose="classifications")
```

This is producing the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidRequestError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-34-c3332cf65668> in <cell line: 2>()
----> 1 result=openai.File.create(file=open("train.jsonl"), purpose="classifications")

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/openai/api_requestor.py in _interpret_response_line(self, rbody,      rcode, rheaders, stream)
    681         stream_error = stream and "error" in resp.data
    682         if stream_error or not 200 <= rcode < 300:
--> 683             raise self.handle_error_response(
    684                 rbody, rcode, resp.data, rheaders, stream_error=stream_error
    685             )

InvalidRequestError: 'classifications' is not one of ['fine-tune'] - 'purpose'
```

On further digging, I came to know that OpenAI removed classification, answers, search in 2021.

Is there a way that I can get the job done without classification?

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the [OpenAi Cookbook](https://github.com/openai/openai-cookbook) under Fine-tuning GPT-3 for:

- [Guide: best practices for fine-tuning GPT-3 to classify text](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1rqj7dkuvl7Byd5KQPUJRxc19BJt8wo0yHNwK84KfU3Q/edit)
- [Fine-tuned classification](https://github.com/openai/openai-cookbook/blob/main/examples/Fine-tuned_classification.ipynb)

These should help to how to use fine-tuning for classification.